# If $\vdash A$, then $\vdash A[x:=t]$

Tags: logic

Let $A$ be a formula, $x$ a variable, $t$ a term and $\Gamma$ a set of formulas. If $\Gamma\vdash A$ and $x$ is not a free variable of some open assumption, then $\Gamma\vdash A\to\forall_xA$ and $\vdash \forall_xA\to A[x:=t]$ by the natural deduction rules. Thus, $\Gamma\vdash A[x:=t]$.

However, I was just told that $$\tag{1}\text{If }\vdash A\text{, then }\vdash A[x:=t]$$ is also true when $x$ is a free variable of $A$. I have the impression that $(1)$ does not follow from the natural deduction rules and I hope someone can elaborate on this. Is $(1)$ an additional axiom?

---

**Addendum**: Maybe I should mention how derivability was defined in my lecture:

Definition: A formula $A$ is called derivable in minimal logic, written $\vdash A$, if there is a derivation of $A$ without free assumptions using
the natural deduction rules. $A$ is called derivable from assumptions $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ if there is a derivation of $A$ with free assumptions among
$A_1, \ldots, A_n$. Let $\Gamma$ be a set of formulas. We write $\Gamma\vdash A$ if
the formula $A$ is derivable from finitely many assumptions $A_1,\ldots , A_n \in\Gamma$.

Comment: How do you interpret "$\vdash A$" when $A$ is not a closed formula? It's either nonsense or it means that $A$ is provable no matter what terms you put for the free variables.

Comment: @Karl From my lecture notes: A formula $A$ is called derivable in minimal logic, written $\vdash A$, if there is a derivation of $A$ without free assumptions using
the natural deduction rules.

Comment: Also note that your conclusion that $\vdash A\to A[x:=t]$ when $x$ is *not* free in $A$ is sort of vacuously true, since $[x:=t]$ only modifies free occurrences of $x$.

Comment: Right, so how would one derive a formula containing a free variable?

Comment: @Karl I don't really know what to answer. We simply assume that $A$ is derivable. Maybe we can even consider the case $\Gamma\vdash A$ and ask if this implies $\Gamma\vdash A[x:=t]$. Of course, the fact that I don't see a problem doesn't mean that there isn't one.

Comment: I think the point is that if we can derive a formula that contains a free variable, then we aren't using any properties of that "term", so the same derivation should work using any term $t$ in its place.

Comment: @Karl Am I missing something or is the title of my question simply a special case of the first paragraph of my question, namely the case $\Gamma=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your [most recent comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317727/if-vdash-a-then-vdash-ax-t#comment8998558_4317727), yes, (1) is a special case when $\Gamma$ is empty.

I'm not exactly sure what part of the argument in the introduction you're skeptical of. I'm writing the answer under the assumption that it's the *side condition* that we impose on $\Gamma$. If this is mistaken, I'll amend my answer. I'm trying to avoid retreating to the *semantics of first-order minimal logic* (which is the system I think you're working in).

---

So, we have a way of eliminating the pesky side condition that $x$ does not occur as a free variable of any open assumption. That side condition is very convenient to use in a proof calculus though.

$$ \frac{\Gamma \vdash A}{\Gamma[x := t] \vdash A[x:=t]} \;\; \text{holds} $$

Imposing the side condition is just a way of making sure that $\Gamma$ is equal to $\Gamma[x:=t]$.

When $\Gamma$ is empty the side condition is trivial since $\varnothing$ never contains any formulas and thus never contains any free variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The problem is that we haven't really discussed when and how the expression $A[x:=t]$ is defined in the lecture. I have the impression that you are using the following fact: If $x$ is not free in $B$, then $B[x:=t]=B$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, what you are saying is correct. $A[x:=t]$ is equal to $A$ if and only if $x$ is equal to $t$ or $x \not\in \text{FV}(A)$. Let $\text{FV}(A)$ refer to the free variables of $A$. $A[x:=t]$ can be defined inductively on formulas by finding free occurrences of $x$ and replacing them with $t$. There is some complexity that you have to deal with if $t$ itself has free variables that might end up being captured. For example, what should the following mean: $(\forall y \mathop. x =y)[y := f(x)]$ ? I don't think there's one universal convention for how to deal with this problem.